# How to convert logical drive to primary drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have HP Laptop with Windows 7 Home edition 32 bits. I create a new drive (F:) that is logical drive that I want to convert that drive in to Primary drive. Because in case OS will reinstalled than that logical drive will be deleted.So, our all data will be lost.

Comment: if it's actually a separate partition, no, it will not be deleted when the OS is reinstalled, unless you chose to delete it or reformat it during the install process.  if it's not really a separate partition but is, say, a .iso or .vhd file that you've mounted, yes, it would be deleted if you reformatted & reinstalled your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Why would the logical drive be deleted if you reinstall?

A logical (extended) partition is just a special type of primary partition that is used to enclose other partitions in order to overcome the [4 primary partition limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) and is a proper partition in its own right, meaning that deletion of the Windows (on another partition) will have no effect on the extended partition.

Unless I'm missing something and you are using [Dynamic Disks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_disk) in which case there is [mixed info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308424) on how easy it is to [convert back to a basic disk system](http://mypkb.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/how-to-non-destructively-convert-dynamic-disks-to-basic-disks/).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your main concern is data loss with a reinstall. The best way to protect against that is to backup your data to an external source. If you follow the "3-2-1 Backup Strategy" you will never lose data if you do it correctly.

- A total of 3 copies of your data
- 2 copies held locally to prevent from local disaster, written onto 2 different disk types
- 1 copy held offsite

While that is a little extreme, you should at least burn all of your data to DVD before you start tinkering with the OS installer.

You could also swap out the hard drive with a new one and install the OS and then copy your data down to the new machine using a SATA to USB adapter. You could easily find laptop hard drives for under $50 and the adapters are cheap.

While you could mess around with disk partitions, it's complicated and can easily break a number of things. Windows installs best when installed to an empty drive. Going down your current path will probably result in a few long nights of pulling out your hair.